Ender 3 V2 Neo with PLA warping and not sticking on one area
I am having trouble trying to print on the bottom side with the filaments not sticking and causing a mess.
The pictures provided are taken from different prints in case you're wondering why they don't look the same.
I managed to 'bodge' this issue by raising the nozzle temperature from 220 °C to 230 °C and bed temperature from 60 °C to 80 °C, then slowing the speed from 100 mm/s to 70 mm/s. I have to set these manually though after the preheat phase every time.
It stuck better for the first few layers. Then during the middle of the print, the bottom side warped (especially the corners) and jeopardized the thickness of those edges. I'm wondering why this only happens to the back and not the front sides.





Looks like you need to level your bed. Did you do that?

@st2000 how often do i need to level my bed?

Depends on your printer, some need it before each print, others once per year or just once.

alright i'll try leveling before starting the print with default settings later

update: I tried the leveling feature on my printer, it didn't do anything different, but I did try changing the z-offset from -2.21 to -2.50 and that worked a treat

Good to hear! Question: When you say "tried the leveling feature" did you only run an auto bed leveling (for all I know you might have this set up to occur before every print) or did you physically adjust the height of the bed?

I only ran the auto bed leveling which is not set to run before every print, I didn't see any change with the print quality after that, so I checked some bed leveling infographics and decided that the z-offset needs to be lower/closer to bed based on how loosely the filaments adhere to each other

You have to manually level the bed first, to get an approximate location. Then you use the automatic bed leveling (ABL) to fine-tune the settings. You've apparently not done the manual leveling first. You should not be adjusting the z-axis settings to deal with this sort of issue - you should be doing things properly so that you're not fighting against the printer all the time. There are limitations to what ABL can do. There are great videos available on YouTube that teach you how to manually level the print bed.

https://www.google.com/search?q=ender+3+neo+print+bed+leveling+site%3Ayoutube.com will help you find some useful videos on YouTube

Relevel your bed!
The pattern of your extrusion being laid out on the bed is very typical for the bed being too low. The first extrusion layer should form a flat, solid plate, not distinct lines next to one another.
Build surfaces are a consumable
The build surface looks very smooth and shiny in some areas, indicating it might be worn out to the point that it offers less grip than when new. This exasperates any adhesion problem from bad bed leveling.

I used to have the exact same issue with my Ender 3. I fixed it by applying some glue to the plate before it started printing; the glue makes the filament stick and not drag behind the toolhead without adhering. Additionally, you might want to try manually leveling the bed instead of using the ABL feature. It can be a bit of a pain, but sometimes the algorithm just doesn't work.
As for the glue, I find you can just use Elmer's Glue Sticks, you usually don't need to buy the special 3D printer glue.
